# custom half star rating in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Before describing my problem, I would like to announce the star rating which I am doing is just for learning and fun purpose so I am not using external library. I am also not re-inventing a new wheel.

I thought of practicing reactjs by developing a half star rating which would bring lot of fun in learning. It is fun still but I am getting trouble on developing half star rating. I could only rate non-decimal like 1 to 5 but i wanted the half part too. On hovering how do i decide if my mouse pointer is in the half of star or not or while clicking.

Can anyone please help me by giving an idea on how to do half star rating? I am using ionicons for the star. Here is my code

```
class Rating extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      rating: this.props.rating || null,
      temp_rating: null
    };
  }

  handleMouseover(rating) {
    this.setState(prev => ({
      rating,
      temp_rating: prev.rating
    }));
  }

  handleMouseout() {

    this.setState(prev => ({
      rating: prev.temp_rating
    }));
  }

  rate(rating) {
    this.setState({
      rating,
      temp_rating: rating
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { rating } = this.state;
    let stars = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      console.log('i', i);
      let klass = "ion-ios-star-outline";
      if (this.state.rating >= i && this.state.rating !== null) {
        klass = "ion-ios-star";
      }
      stars.push(
        <i
          className={klass}
          onMouseOver={() => this.handleMouseover(i)}
          onClick={() => this.rate(i)}
          onMouseOut={() => this.handleMouseout()}
        />
      );
    }
    return (
      <div className="rating">
        {stars}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Rating;
```

for demo you can see https://codesandbox.io/s/ll9kpn5lvm .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: Instead of using 5 divs with a full star in each, use 10 divs with half a star in each. Each div is too narrow to hold a full star, and you can use `overflow: hidden` to hide the other half.

Example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/xpl2wjpyoq

I put the style inside the component because I could not find the CSS sheet, but you should include that in the CSS.

Relevant code:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  let klass = "ion-ios-star-outline";
  if (this.state.rating >= i && this.state.rating !== null) {
    klass = "ion-ios-star";
  }
  stars.push(
    <i
      style={{ 
          display: "inline-block", 
          width: "7px", 
          overflow: "hidden", 
          direction: (i%2===0) ? "ltr" : "rtl"
      }}
      className={klass}
      onMouseOver={() => this.handleMouseover(i)}
      onClick={() => this.rate(i)}
      onMouseOut={() => this.handleMouseout()}
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: Sorry I did not understand it clearly. Could you explain a bit, please?

Comment: sorry for my insufficient knowledge, but I am using for(i=0;i<5;i++) to display star where there is not talk about non-integer.

Comment: If you don't mind, can you show me the way to show half-star along with full star in the https://codesandbox.io/s/ll9kpn5lvm, please? Just pseudocode will work.

Comment: To explain, a star takes 14px, and you put it in a 7px container. So it overflows, and you hide half with overflow:hidden. To overflow to the left every second star (so that it displays the other side), I change the text direction to be from right to left ("rtl").

Comment: oh so direction and overflow was the main logic to hide the stars for non-integer?

Comment: @milan Just an idea, there are certainly other ways to do it! For example comparing the cursor position with the size of the 5 stars' container.

Comment: wow thanks for the help and idea. This one is easy to understand. You nailed it. I appreciate your help.